# Action to same page instead of another

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms

I have a `form` with a `select` in it that looks like this

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="?page_id=12" role="search">
    <select name="s" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <?php $cats = get_categories( array( 'hide_empty' => 0 ) ); ?>
        <?php foreach ( $cats as $cat ) {
            echo "<option value=" . $cat->cat_name . ">" . $cat->cat_name . "</option>";
        }; ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

When I select an option from the select list it submits the form, but instead of going to `?page=12&s=value` it goes to `?s=value`.

I've tried `action=#` but then it goes to `?s=value#` which is not what I want.

How do I get it so that it redirects to `?page=12&s=value`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, you need to have both parameter inside the form so that they both get added to the querystring

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="" role="search">
    <input type="hidden" name="page_id" value="12">
    <select name="s" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <?php $cats = get_categories( array( 'hide_empty' => 0 ) ); ?>
        <?php foreach ( $cats as $cat ) {
            echo "<option value=" . $cat->cat_name . ">" . $cat->cat_name . "</option>";
        }; ?>
    </select>
</form>
```